# A question about the span of a sequence of polynomials satisfying a linear recurrence

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, polynomials, computability-theory, finite-fields, recurrences

Let F be a finite field and A(n) in F[t], n in N, be defined by a linear recurrence with coefficients in F[t], together with initial conditions. Is there a decision procedure for determining whether the A(n) span F[t] over F? 
--- Example 1: F=Z/2. $A(n+6)= t^6A(n) + tA(n+1) + t^4A(n+2) + t^2A(n+4)$. The initial values are: $A(0) = A(1) = A(2) = A(3) = A(4) = 0$, $A(5) = 1$.

--- Example 2: F=Z/2. $A(n+4)=t^4A(n) + t^2A(n+1) + tA(n+2)$. Initial values: $A(0) = A(1) =0, A(2) = 1, A(3) = t$.

Example 1 arises from the theory of level 1 elliptic modular forms over Z/2. The A(n) do span--there is a proof using the theory of the Hecke operator T5 on this space of forms, due to Nicolas and Serre, which involves a lot of messy computation as well. (There's also an elementary not as messy proof I've concocted).

My guess is that the A(n) of the ad hoc Example 2 span as well, even though there is no underlying Hecke theory. But I've no idea how to handle such questions in general. To illustrate the difficulties note that in Example 2, the smallest n such that $t^{43}$ is a sum of A(k) with k at most n is 2192. And the smallest n such that $t^{107}$ is a sum of A(k) with k at most n is 3989.

Comment: In the formula for $A(n+6)$, is $tA(n+1)$ right? or, should it be $t^5A(n+1)$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson: there's no way those $A(n)$ would span $F[t]$ if it was $t^5$.

Comment: @Sam, OK, I was just doing a little naive pattern-matching.

Comment: Is it just a coincidence that the coefficients of the recurrence relation are all monomials? I don't have any ideas for settling the question (and no clue whether that plays a role), it just feels like a coincidence, but may be there is a reason this happens with the sequences that naturally appears in your context

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen. There's no reason. For example there are very complicated recursions analogous to those of Example 1 coming from the theory of Hecke operators acting on elliptic modular forms over Z/3 of levels Gamma_0 (N) where N is 5 or 13, and the computer strongly suggests rather astonishing results which would answer my question positively in these cases, and, more interestingly, give explicit results about Hecke algebras in these levels . By the way I made a mistake in my explication of Example 2; I should have written t^42 and t^106, not t^43 and t^107.